# Readfile: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, ассемблер

Задача: нужно из С++ в ассемблерной вставке обработать текстовый файл, используя функции WinAPI.

При вызове ReadFile программа выдаёт:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7692DEB5 (KernelBase.dll) в
>   XXX.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу
>   0x00000000.

вот кусок кода, связанный с проблемой:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char filename[256] = "text.txt"; //имя исходного файла с текстом
    OFSTRUCT buffer;
    HFILE pfile; 
    DWORD filesize; //размер файла
    BYTE * pbuf;

    setlocale(0, "");
__asm
    {
        //Открытие файла
        push OF_READ
        lea eax, buffer
        push eax
        lea eax, filename
        push eax
        call DWORD PTR OpenFile
        cmp eax, -1
        je fopen_error
        mov pfile, eax

        //Получение его размера
        push NULL
        push pfile 
        call GetFileSize //вызываем функцию подсчёта размера файла, результат в ax
        mov filesize, eax  //записываем в переменную

        //Выделение памяти для чтения файла в буфер
        mov eax, filesize
        inc eax
        push eax
        call malloc
        mov pbuf, eax
        add esp, 4

        //Чтение в буфер
        push NULL
        push NULL
        PUSH filesize
        push pbuf
        push pfile
        call ReadFile  // вот тут и возникает проблема
```

Причём у друга на Win10 Visual studio 2017 этот же код работает без проблем, а у меня на Win7 Visual studio 2017 выдаёт это исключение. И даже экзешник с этим кодом, один и тот же, у него работает а у меня нет.

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема? Наверное я упускаю из вида что-то очевидное?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, в чём было дело.

Там функция же требует на вход переменную для записи количества реально считанных/записанных байт, а там был NULL, вот она и пыталась записать значение вникуда. Возможно на вин10 WinAPI работает несколько иначе и видя нуль просто не выдаёт значение и идёт дальше

```
DWORD dwBytesRead; 

push NULL 
lea eax, [dwBytesRead] 
push eax 
PUSH filesize 
push pbuf 
push pfile 
call DWORD PTR ReadFile
```

с writefile то же самое

видимо WinAPI и логика его работы могут несколько отличаться на разных версиях винды